# Problem with autofilling output layer names while batch processing

Tags: qgis, python, gui, batch

I've been using QGIS "Raster boolean OR" to batch process a set of rasters (using LTS version 3.16.6). This has been working as hoped/expected, with the exception that I've not been able to get autofill to use the input layer names when generating the output layer names. When I select the raster layer inputs, they populate the "Input layers" column as a list of "1 inputs selected"-elements, which doesn't seem to provide a readable parameter when using the autofill settings:

[image: The batch processing dialogue showing the populated input list]

[image]

When trying to use the autofill function to generate the output layer names using the input layer names it throws me a python error (which I think is saying it's unable to read the list of inputs):

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\BatchOutputSelectionPanel.py",
> line 112, in showSelectionDialog
> if v in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers(): TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I've been unable to find any clues as to how to work around this problem. I haven't even seen any examples of people experiencing similar issues.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Had a little look at other batch processing dialogues, and I think the issue might be down to the fact that "Raster boolean OR" accepts multiple inputs for each operation. Because of this, the table is set up in a certain way, and displays a list of "1 inputs selected"-boxes instead of the actual, singular names of the inputs that I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after some more hours of tinkering I was able to find a workaround for this issue. I put the operation into a graphical processing model that only takes one input. This way the batch processing dialogue worked the way I needed it to when running the processing model. Leaving this up here in case more people run into the same problems!